# Heap allocation and suitable hardware

Tags: java, c#, performance, heap-memory

For a C# .net 3.5 application which unavoidably creates a lot of data on the heap, in terms of hardware what would I be looking for in terms of memory? Would it just be the largest socket bus width? Or the "bandwidth" of the memory sticks? Or the actual frequency they run at?

We have concluded the bottleneck of our application cannot be avoided and when scaling up, spreading the work over multiple threads we seem to be getting "collisions" due to many threads accessing the RAM.

The actual problem refers to locking on items and having many threads trying to access these items. There is no way to further optimise the threading locking. As this relates to  threading I wasn't sure whether I should also investigate alternative CPU choices and also closely look at the QPI statistics? We are currently using the Westmere architecture but a slow clock speed of 2GHz.

EDIT: Has been suggested DMA is what could help us.

I'm going to tag this as C# and Java, because I believe the answer will not be C#-specific.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: How do you know there is no way to further optimise the locking?

Comment: @Henk, 4x Physical CPUs of 8 logical cores (4x Xeon x7550)

Comment: @DNA, I have been told there is no way the software can be optimised and if it could, it is too far past the point of no return, hence hardware options need to be considered.

Comment: I'm afraid we're not really in a position to answer this: we don't know your application's characteristics; we don't have access to your hardware. The best option is probably for *you* to profile *your* application on *your* hardware and see where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: Hi LukeH, I didn't say there is not enough memory. There is a delay due to threading and it appears the memory bus is being maxed out. Was asking for advice relating to memory bus specifications which could help solve this.

Comment: @user1107474: Yep, sorry, I just removed that part of my comment. The general principle still applies though -- we can't tell what-and-where your app's performance bottlenecks are; a profiler can.

Comment: @Luke, The profiling has been done by somebody else and the conclusion was that thread-locking was causing the delay and we cannot re-write this. I have just been tasked to research what hardware upgrades could possibly help. I appreciate I am kinda asking for a free lunch, but I dont have the freedom to change the code and they wont consider it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would test the application on a faster machine. From the sounds of it, your memory bandwidth is the bottle neck, so I would try a 4.5 GHz over clocked i7 with 32 GB of 1600 MHz memory or similar. You can buy one for about $1000. You may find that with a much faster system your bottle neck moves.

BTW: I doubt that object creation in C# is avoidable, though it might be not achieveable as it sounds like to have limited time to fix this. In Java, I have written a number of high performance servers which GCes less than once per day, but you have to write all the core code with objective. Similarly you can write a service which does not lock in critical sections of code, but its not trival to just add this later.

Comment: Hello again! Thank you for helping last week. Regarding this issue, do you think the CPU speed would make much difference (should state we're using Xeons on a server at the moment, so overclocked i7 isnt feasible)? Also, you mention memory speed, but not the interface width? I presume double the speed but half the width would give as good performance as half the speed but double the width- they both give the same theoretical bandwidth??

Comment: Forgot to ask, are there any particularly good architectures (Intel and AMD) for the memory bus? I have heard opterons have always had a better memory bus than Intel

Comment: I believe that was true until Sandy Bridge which when it came out was the fastest. It likely that AMD have something even better now or at least planned.

Comment: You may find you have to buy one of each to work out whats best for your application.  The over clocked Intels can be 25% to 80% fastest than the previous generation Xeons.